# Form submit giving error in javascript (Access is denied)

Tags: javascript, html, forms, iframe

I am submitting a form from javascript and it is giving error at form.submit().

HTML:

```
<form >
    <input type="file" name="filetype" onchange="uploadFile(this.form);" name="file" />
</form>
```

JS:

```
function uploadFile(form){
   var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
   iframe.setAttribute("id", "upload_iframe");
   iframe.setAttribute("name", "upload_iframe");
   form.parentNode.appendChild(iframe);
   form.setAttribute("target", "upload_iframe");
   form.setAttribute("action", "abcd.do");
   form.setAttribute("method", "post");
   form.setAttribute("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
   form.setAttribute("encoding", "multipart/form-data"); 
   form.submit(); /// error is here (SCRIPT5: Access denied)
}
```

I have tried putting iframe's source as a file in same domain but that too didn't work.
This is working very wekk in **MOZILLA** but giving described error in **IE**.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SCRIPT5: Access is denied in IE9 on file upload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138859/script5-access-is-denied-in-ie9-on-file-upload)

Comment: hi I have already tried putting source of iframe to an existing small html as i explained but didn't work for me

Comment: even getting the same error using ajaxSubmit jQuery library